# updating a line in file without using 2nd file

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to update a file, but only certain lines.  There are a lot of lines and I don't want to rewrite the whole file to update it. 
Ex. out of 4k line i need to change 5 item in n-th item

Most answers on this question use two files or rewrite it completely. I am wondering if there is a more effective command for this, one that can attack one line at a time without writing the whole file at the end of the process. If no possible way, what would be most efficient way to do so.

I used Python 2.7

Comment: you need to rewrite whole file ... at least using python not sure about other languages...

Comment: The issue you're going to run in to is that while its possible to write over a specific byte range of an existing file, CSV files aren't set up to support that.  Your new line would have to be exactly the same number of bytes as the line you are trying to replace.  It is not possible to grow/shrink a portion of a file without rewriting the whole thing.

Comment: Even if it were possible in general (which it's not), this seems like very premature optimization to me -- 4k is very small.  It takes me between 0.01 and 0.02 seconds to write that out, with each line having about ~200 characters.  I would have to do that more than 6000 times even to match the time it took to try it to write this comment.

Comment: Here are some good samples http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/285837/editing-csv-files#.  This is using the `csv` module.

Comment: basically I should shut up and just rewrite the whole file? I just thought it would be wise to do it for the future, since the file is growing everyday. I will convert it to database at some point but right now just a file.

Comment: A database is definitely the way to go once you've outgrown a flat file.

Comment: The only way to avoid rewriting the entire file would be to get down below the level of files and write your own randomly-accessible sequence of blocks (or separate files) that acts like a file. That isn't impossible, but it's very complex—and it means you lose many performance benefits that your OS, filesystem, C library, and Python implementation give you for free. That's all reasonable if you're writing, say, an RDBMS or a filesystem, but otherwise, no.

Comment: If you want a relatively easy to use database with Python, you could try sqlite3 http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html.  Another lightweight solution (in my opinion) is a nosql solution like Redis.  If you must use files, I agree with Joran Beasley.  How to write an efficient solution depends on the specifics of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, files on the disk are just a sequence of *bytes*. And not an intelligently stored sequence of *lines*. 
That is, you can alter the n'th line in your file, if and only if, the amount of bytes it contains remains the same after that operation.

If your csv format allows to contain arbitrary amounts of insignificant whitespace as part of those lines, you could make them large enough to hold any data you may ever write to it (say a fixed large-enough-line-size). Then you can update single lines without a rewrite of the entire file. You need to make sure that you overwrite the previous content (if any), though.